# visual studio keyboard scheme not working

Tags: visual-studio

My shortcuts in visual studio 2022 aren't working anymore.
when I try Ctrl K + Ctrl + D
it says
`(Ctrl+K) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...`
When I go to `Edit/Advanced/Format document` this does work.
When I go to `tools/options/Environement/Keyboard` I can select `(Defualt)` and key shortcut tips are there but won't work.
When I click `Reset` it always resets to `Visual C# 2005` and the shortcut tips change but don't work either.

I already tried repairing the installation. but can't find why my shortcuts are broken.
My available keyboard mappings are

am I maybe missing one?

I tried repairing visual studio, changing the settings.